# Upgrade project from 9.1.3 to version 10 PrimeNG for Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

Now I upgrade project version 9.1.3 to version 10 PrimeNG and I see some change here
[error change structure folder import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrIlM.png)

- ConfirmationService not import from 'primeng' and it's move to other folder, Does we have some quick change for all file import of project? because the project have too many files need to repair

Please help me to check this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To import **MessageService** from **PrimeNG** version 10 use the below import statement:

**import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';**

as MessageService located in primeng api